# Template Friend Function / Class forward declaration

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration

Why do we need template forward declaration for `BlobPtr` and operator overloading for template.

```cpp
template <typename> class BlobPtr;
template <typename> class Blob; 

template <typename T>
    bool operator==(const Blob<T>&, const Blob<T>&); 

template <typename T> 
class Blob {
    friend class BlobPtr<T>; 
    friend bool operator==<T>
        (const Blob<T>&, const Blob<T>&); 

};
class BlobPtr<T>{};

Blob<char> ca; 

Blob<int> ia;
```

For for nontemplate class, forward declaration is not needed.

```cpp
class Blob {
type
    
   class BlobPtr; 
   friend bool operator==
        (const Blob&, const Blob&); 

};
class BlobPtr{};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to declare the template in a friend declaration, you can just do that, you don't need forward declarations:

```
template <typename T> 
class Blob {
    template <typename U>
    friend class BlobPtr;     

    template <typename U>
    friend bool operator==(const Blob<U>&, const Blob<U>&); 
};
```

This declares  all instances of the templates as friends, not just the matching one. That is, `BlobPtr<int>` and `BlobPtr<long>` (and generally `BlobPtr<Anything>`) are all friends of `Blob<int>`.

If you want to declare a particular specialization of a template as a friend (so that `BlobPtr<int>` is a friend of `Blob<int>` but `BlobPtr<long>` is not), then you first need to tell the compiler that `BlobPtr` is a template in the first place - that's what you need forward declaration for.